# Localizer ressources not resolved in published version

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a strange problem. In my asp.net core 5 project I am using localizer. And it's working like a charm on my developer machine. But after publishing the project and running on a dedicated server the ressources are not resolved.

Startup.cs

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false).AddViewLocalization().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
            services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization();
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
                options =>
                {
                    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                        {
                            new CultureInfo("de-CH"),
                            new CultureInfo("en-US")
                        };

                    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "de-CH", uiCulture: "de-CH");
                    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
            app.UseRequestLocalization();

            var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
        }
```

Index.cshtlm

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<p>@Localizer["TextResetPassword"]</p>
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Check">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="error_message">
            <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" placeholder="@Localizer["TextExampleUsername"]" />
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="@Localizer["TextSendButton"]">
</form>
```

I also have the ressources under "Ressources/Views.Home.Index.de.resx" or "Ressources/Views.Home.Index.en.resx". These host the corresponding entries for the labels.

If I run on my developer machine the label "TextResetPassword" is resolved correctly to the entrie in my ressource.
But after publishing the project and installing on the server it returns the text "TextResetPassword" and not the entrie of the ressource.

I already tried the following steps:

1. Marked the ressources in the project as "Copy always"
2. The packages Localization.AspNetCore.TagHelpers and Microsoft.Extensions.Localization are installed

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some digging I found the answer. And it was the developer in front of the pc ...

I was expecting that the language was sended by the client. But I was wrong the problem was in startup.cs:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRequestLocalization();
            var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
```

app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute() has to be called at last, otherwise it returns immediately and the app.UseRequestLocalization() was ignored.
Second problem was my laziness and some string in englisch were missing.